# Learning makefiles

Tags: c, syntax, makefile

I am trying to learn makefiles.  I have to do an assignment for my Unix admin/programming class that involves creating a makefile for three files:  savings.h savings.cpp and savingsTest.cpp.  My teacher didn't really explain much to us about makefiles.  I looked in my book and I understand the general idea but I am having trouble with the syntax.  I followed the example my book has but I get an error.  Here is my code for the makefile so far:

```
 savingsTest.0:  savingsTest.cpp savings.cpp savings.h
                 cc -c savingsTest.cpp

 savings.o:  savings.cpp savings.h
             cc -c savings.cpp
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  cc -c savingsTest.cpp
  cc: No input file specified, no output generated
  *** Error code 1
  make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `savingsTest'
  v245-2% emacs makefile.txt
```

Can somebody please help me understand the syntax so I can determine what I am doing wrong.  Thank you to anybody that responds to help.

Comment: are you compiling in the directory where savingsTest.cpp is stored?

Comment: A .cpp extension usually denotes a C++ file. I'm guessing your C-only compiler "cc" doesn't recognize it as a valid input file.  What book did you get this example from?

Comment: Please look at this tutorial for <code>makefile</code> creation.  http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: Start with the [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) tutorials and online manuals. It *incredibly* flexible (though admittedly tedious at times to manage).

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort out the name of your C++ compiler.  I'm about to assume it is `CC`, but there are lots of other names (`g++` for instance).

Your program `savingsTest.0` depends on two object files: `savings.o` and `savingsTest.o`.  The `savings.o` file depends on `savings.cpp` and `savings.h`.  The `savingsTest.o` file depends on `savingsTest.cpp` and `savings.h`.

That's all written as:

```
savingsTest.0: savings.o savingsTest.o
        CC -o $@ savings.o savingsTest.o

savingsTest.o: savingsTest.cpp savings.h
        CC -c savingsTest.cpp
savings.o: savings.cpp savings.h
        CC -c savings.cpp
```

You could probably leave out the last two command lines; `make` knows how to compile a `.cpp` to `.o`.

You'll learn to use macros in your `makefile`.  `$@` is the name of the program or file being built (so it is a shorthand for `savingsTest.0`).  There are reasons to use it — notably, don't repeat yourself.

You should normally use macros for commands and command arguments, for libraries, and for lists of files.